# LINQ query to select by oldest and by id

Tags: c#, linq

I am having this issue to select items. By now I am using this query:

```
var eventQuery = dbContext.ClientEvents
                          .Where(f => f.ClientEventStatusLogs.Any(e => e.StatusId == 2))
                          .Select(TransformEvent());
```

`ClientEvents` is a list of events and every event can have another list of `ClientEventStatusLogs`. This query works fine most of the time. But If I have new `ClientEventStatusLogs` on this event with `StatusId` not 2 it will still gives me this `ClientEvent`, because of ANY. `ClientEventStatusLogs` have date column, so I would like to check `if StatusId == 2` only for the latest log.

I hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want

```
dbContext.ClientEvents.Where(
    f => f.ClientEventStatusLogs
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.Date)
        .FirstOrDefault()?.StatusId == 2)
```

Just change `Date` to whatever the date property name is.